# IF statement only appears if numbers 4 through 9 are chosen within form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that lets users choose a quantity of products that are available. If the user chooses a number 4 through 9 while there are over 10 available, my validation statement appears. I've used console.log to see if the numbers are submitting correctly and everything looks fine, The if statement shouldn't appear because 4-9 aren't greater than what's available.

The form:

```
    <form action="add_cart.php" method="POST" id="add_product_form">

      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?=$id;?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="available" id="available" value="">

       <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-xs-9">

            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>

            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" 

            name="quantity" min = "0" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9"></div>

        <br><br><br>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-9">

            <label form="size">Size:</label>

        <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">

    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Size</option>

<?php

foreach ($size_array as $string) {

$string_array = explode(':', $string);

$size = $string_array[0];

$available = $string_array[1];

if ($available > 0) {
    echo '<option value="'.$size.'" data-available="'.$available.'">'.$size.' 
('.$available.' available)</option>';

}

}

?>
</select>
</div>
</div>


<option value="28" ></option>

</form>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="closeModal();">Close</button>

        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="add_to_cart(); return 

false;">Add To Cart <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> . 

</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery('#size').change(function(){

var available = jQuery('#size option:selected').data("available");

jQuery('#available').val(available);

});
```

when submit button is pressed, this method runs:

```
function add_to_cart(){

var size = jQuery('#size').val();

var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();

var available = jQuery('#available').val();

var error = '';

var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();

jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");

if(size == '' ||  quantity == '' || quantity == 0 ){

error += '<p class="text-danger text-center"> You must choose a quantity. 
</p>';

jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);

return;

}

else if (quantity > available ){

error +='<p class="text-danger text-center"> Sorry, it looks like we only have

'+available+' available at this time.</p>';

jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);

}

else{
jQuery.ajax({
       url: '/onlineStore/admin/parsers/add_cart.php',
    method: 'POST',
      data: data,
   success: function(){
    location.reload();
   },
     error: function(){alert("something went wrong.");}
});
}

}
```

Only when the numbers 4 through 9 are chosen, the (quantity > available) if statement shows when it shouldn't. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: If you don’t convert `quantity` and `available` to numbers, those strings are compared alphanumerically rather than numerically.

Comment: sidenote: you can store `available` as a normal var, don't need to go via an hidden element. Or put `var available = jQuery('#size option:selected').data("available");` in `add_to_cart()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As values of fields are **strings**, you compare strings, not numbers. Convert values to numbers, either with `+` or `parseInt`:

```
var quantity = parseInt(jQuery('#quantity').val());
var available = parseInt(jQuery('#available').val());
```

In this case you should also look for `NaN` values which happen when you convert empty string or some non-numeric string to number.